# Does running "rm -P /path/to/file" secure erase file from a data forensic perspective when used on spinning disk?

Tags: deletion

According to `man rm`:

> Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are
> overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff,
> then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted.

How does this compare to the following (used to secure erase whole disk) from a data forensic perspective?

```
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1
```

As a side note, it is my understanding that secure erasing files doesn't work on flash drives or SSDs. Is this understanding correct or is there a secure workaround?

Comment: I'm aware of a **-P** option for **rm**, perhaps you are thinking of *rmdir*? In any case, many variants of this question exist. Here is a link to one of my answers. The question was about the *Cipher* commnd, but the answer addresses your questions. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206257/how-secure-is-the-windows-cipher-command/206512#206512

Comment: @user10216038 As far as I know, the `-P` option is not available in the GNU coreutils' version of `rm`, but is available in BSD's implementation of `rm`

Comment: @nobody - I don't keep up with BSD, thanks! Given the same hardware, overwriting 3 times, vice 1, is still pointless.

Comment: @user10216038 Yes, its a waste of time on modern hardware. Not sure why BSD still kept it that way.

Comment: @user10216038 I believe multiple passes is required when using flash drives or SSDs because of wear levelling.

Comment: @sunknudsen - No, multiple writes will not address wear leveling.